# matplotlib puts unwanted zeros below my subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

As you can see I get unwanted zeros below every subplot

[image]

Here is the code

```
fig3,axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=5)
fig3.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.8,top = 0.9  )

A.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[0,0])
axes[0][0].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[0][0].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[0][0].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[0][0].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[0][0].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[0][0].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[0][0].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

B.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[1,0])
axes[1][0].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[1][0].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[1][0].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[1][0].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[1][0].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[1][0].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[1][0].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

C.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[2,0])
axes[2][0].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[2][0].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[2][0].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[2][0].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[2][0].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[2][0].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[2][0].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

D.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[3,0])
axes[3][0].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[3][0].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[3][0].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[3][0].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[3][0].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[3][0].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[3][0].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

E.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[4,0])
axes[4][0].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[4][0].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[4][0].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[4][0].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[4][0].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[4][0].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[4][0].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

F.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[0,1])
axes[0][1].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[0][1].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[0][1].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[0][1].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[0][1].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[0][1].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[0][1].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

G.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[1,1])
axes[1][1].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[1][1].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[1][1].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[1][1].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[1][1].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[1][1].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[1][1].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

H.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[2,1])
axes[2][1].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[2][1].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[2][1].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[2][1].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[2][1].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[2][1].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[2][1].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

I.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[3,1])
axes[3][1].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[3][1].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[3][1].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[3][1].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[3][1].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[3][1].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[3][1].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])

J.plot(x=0,y=1, linewidth=0.4,color='k',legend=False,ax=axes[4,1])
axes[4][1].axvline(indices.loc[0,Indice],color='b')
axes[4][1].axvline(indices.loc[1,Indice],color='b')
axes[4][1].axvline(indices.loc[2,Indice],color='k')
axes[4][1].axvline(indices.loc[3,Indice],color='k')
axes[4][1].axvline(indices.loc[4,Indice],color='r')
axes[4][1].axvline(indices.loc[5,Indice],color='r')
axes[4][1].set_xlim([indices.loc[0,Indice]-10,indices.loc[5,Indice]+10])
axes[4][1].set_ylim(-.5,2)

plt.show()
```

also I've got multiple plots done this way each one in a different figure I was wondering if there was a way to put them all into an interactive plot that changes between figures at the end?

Comment: You could try using `.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)` to hide the label under the x

Comment: Everything after "also" seems to be a completely different question. If you have two questions ask two questions. Mind two things. First, this is probably unrelated to your real data, so if asking a new question, make sure to provide a [mcve]. Second, it's not actually clear how you would like the plot(s) to look like of what mechanism should determine which plot to show. Those are important bits of information you would then need to include.

Comment: they were two questions , however the important one was the first one , i'll read it , so i can ask more meaningful questions here thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0` you see below the plot is the automatically generated xlabel. You may get rid of it setting it to an empty string:

```
axes[0][0].set_xlabel("")
```